# How to set a complex gradient with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, css, angular

A few notes before I begin my question proper.
One I have looked at the question 'Angular js applying Gradients with ng style' but that doesn't seam to fully answer what I want to do.

Second while I don't believe it matters too much, I wanted to say this is effecting a Fomantic accordion.

Now for my question.  What do I need to do, to take a list of colors and apply them as a gradient to my element?

I have pulled the elment in a method that runs when the accordion element is initialized (called with ng-init) to finish setting it up, so I have attempted set it there based on various examples I've found online, but to no avail. I even commented out some other css styles that effect the background out until I know this is working.

Here is what I currently have in the method (console.logs and all):

```
vm.initializeAccordion = function(question) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var elementId = '#question_accordion_' + question['id'];
                var element = $(elementId);
                element.accordion();
                
                var colors = vm.candidateAssignedTagColors(question);
                
                
                if (colors.length > 0) {
                    var backgroundString = GlobalFunction.getCssValuePrefix() +'linear-gradient(to right';
                    $.each(colors, function(index, color) {
                        var percentage = ((index + 1) / colors.length) * 100;
                        backgroundString += `,${color} ${percentage}%`;
                    });
                    backgroundString += ')';
                    console.log(backgroundString);
                    console.log(element[0].style);
                    element[0].style.backgroundImage = backgroundString;
                }
            });
            
            
        };
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? I have tried setting, style.background, style.backgroundColor, style.backgroundImage and none seam to work.  If this method won't work, what other way could I do it? Somehow with ng-style?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? What is element[0] - it looked as though element was, well, an element rather than a collection or array of elements  (?)

Comment: It comes in as an array with one element. No errors that I see